# Different picture for each heading chapter?

Tags: diagrams

I found a free template as they called "tstextbook" and I believed it was derived from Legrand orange book as a template. It has minitoc on each chapter page while Legrand template does not. Inversely, Legrand template can change chapter heading picture while tstextbook can not do it. I like to have minitoc and be able to chang chapter heading picture at the same time. So, I started with my MWE hopefully I can put them together. I changed picture to example-image-a but it will apply to all chapter heading picture. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

```
% Chapter styling
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
% Numbered chapters (with minitoc)
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node at (current page.north west)
    {
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        % Background image
        \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0)
        {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-a}};
        % Chapter heading
        \draw[anchor=west, inner sep=0pt] (-0.1cm,-1.5cm) node
        [black,
        ultra thick,
        fill=tsorange!10,
        fill opacity=.6,
        inner sep=10pt]
        (0,0)
        {\parbox[t][1.6cm][t]{\paperwidth}
            {\huge\bfseries\sffamily\flushleft\thechapter. #1}};
        % Chapter contents
        \draw[anchor=west,inner sep=0pt] (8.8cm,-7cm) node
        [tssteelblue,
        ultra thick,
        fill=white,
        fill opacity=.8,
        draw=tssteelblue,
        draw opacity=1,
        line width=1.5pt,
        rounded corners,
        inner sep=0pt]
        (0,0)
        {\hspace{1cm}\parbox[t][7.1cm][t]{11cm}
            {\vspace{-1cm}\huge\bfseries\sffamily\flushleft
                \textcolor{black}{\sffamily\minitoc}}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{7.5cm}
}

% Unnumbered chapters (without minitoc)
\renewcommand{\@makeschapterhead}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    % Background image
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0)
    {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-b}};
    % Chapter heading
    \draw[anchor=west,inner sep=0pt] (-0.1cm,-1.5cm) node
    [black,
    ultra thick,
    fill=tsorange!10,
    fill opacity=.6,
    inner sep=10pt]
    (0,0)
    {\parbox[t][1.6cm][t]{\paperwidth}
        {\huge\bfseries\sffamily\flushleft #1}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{8cm}
}
```

Comment: Don't put tikzpictures inside other tikzpictures.  You can put a tikzpicture into a savebox and the box inside a node.

Comment: @JohnKormylo That's the original code. I just replace the original picture with example-image-a just for this MWE. I don't understand those codes.

Comment: Make this a full Minimal Working Example (\documentclass to \end{document}) and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks again for your intention to help but I'm gonna go back to Legrand orange book template and step by step adjust to what I need.